# replace (masking) specific value in HIVE

Tags: regex, hive

Hi gurus i've stumbled in a problem when replacing/masking column data containing account (with no standart length, it could be 10 digit or more), let's say i have data like this:

```
6285669871 already in history  
6281246983002 not in history  
08693461287 not found  
6194637899 already in history
```

what i want is to mask them into ' ..(additional log info)'

i tried using:

```
regexp_replace(Column1,'[0-9]{7}','<account>')
```

but it doesnt work since account number length is not always 7 digit, is there any better approach for this?

thanks

Comment: Try `'[0-9]{7,}'` to match 7 or more digits. Prepend with `^` (`'^[0-9]{7,}'`) if they appear only at the string start.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will do it, i'll update later, thank you for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
regexp_replace(Column1,'^[0-9]{7,}','<account>')
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `[0-9]{7,}` - 7  *or more* digits

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/D53fsk/1).

Comment: Hi, your solutions works like a charm, however we don't really need the '^' because some data is not always begin with account number like 'account number=61135077' is not available'